# What is the assumption made in "Learn You a Haskell" when deducing the kind?

Tags: haskell

This question is not subjective. A very specific verb is used in the referenced book, and I'd like to understand what the implication of that phrasing is, because I'm afraid I'm misunderstanding something.

From [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#recursive-data-structures), the following paragraph is the third and last one containing "we assume `*`".

> ```
> data Barry t k p = Barry { yabba :: p, dabba :: t k }
> ```
>
> And now we want to make it an instance of `Functor`. `Functor` wants types of kind `* -> *` but `Barry` doesn't look like it has that kind. What is the kind of `Barry`? Well, we see it takes three type parameters, so it's going to be `something -> something -> something -> *`. It's safe to say that `p` is a concrete type and thus has a kind of `*`. **For `k`, we assume `*` and so by extension, `t` has a kind of `* -> *`**. Now let's just replace those kinds with the `something`s that we used as placeholders and we see it has a kind of `(* -> *) -> * -> * -> *`.

Why are we assuming anything at all? Upon reading "we assume X (i.e. we assume that X is true)" it is natural for me to think that we should also consider the case that X is false. In the specific case of the example, couldn't `t` be of kind `(* -> *) -> *` and `k` of kind `(* -> *)`? If this was the case, whatever `t` and `k` actually were, `t k` would still be a concrete type, no?

I see that the whole line of reasoning is then checked against the compiler, but I don't think the compiler **assumes**. If it does, I'd like to know what, if it doesn't then again I'm afraid I'm missing the meaning of the paragraph.

Comment: You are correct. Indeed, we can have `k :: L` for any kind `L`, as long as `t :: L -> *`. A compiler here must however choose some specific `L`, or resort to a polykind. A polykind would be the most general option, but here GHC chooses `L = *` (basic Haskell does not have polykinds, they have to be turned on as an extension). Since it chooses something which is rather arbitrary, LYAH uses the word "assume" (AFAICT).

Comment: Ok, maybe _the compiler assumes_ would have puzzled me at least less than _we assume_, or not at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In fact, the compiler does assume! But you can ask it not to with the PolyKinds extension. You can read about it in more detail [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.8.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-PolyKinds). With that extension turned on, the kind of `Barry` will be `forall k. (k -> *) -> k -> * -> *`.

Comment: I have posted a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61738702/making-a-datatype-an-instance-of-functor-to-map-on-a-field-which-is-of-parametri), if you are interested.

Answer (score -1):

Good point. The author makes a needless assumtion. Perhaps just to make it easier to understand in his Type Foo chapter but people like yourself may rightfully question this.

Both  `t`, `k` and `p` are type variables. As we see from `yabba :: p` it can live alone so it's like a constant function, as if it was a value instead of a type, it's type signature would say `Int` or `Char`, whatever... you name it. But since it is a type then it's kind signature is `*`.

However `t` type here takes a type variable `k` to construct a type (`dabba :: t k`) <s>so we are sure that (no assumtion here) `t` has a kind signature like `* -> *` and `k` has `*`</s>.

Once we know this... the type `Barry t k p`'s kind signature is `(* -> *) -> * -> * -> *` which means it takes `t` then `k` and then `p` and give us `Barry` type.

**Edit** Make sure to read @luqui's comment below.

Comment: `k` is not constrained to be `*` as you claim it is while deducing `t`. We could have `k :: * -> *` and `t :: (* -> *) -> *`, for example.  Add a field `doo :: k Int` to the record and it will pass with no issue.

Comment: @luqui.. Yes you are right... I won't delete this answer since your comment is really worth standing.