# Making a datatype an instance of Functor to map on a field which is of parametric type

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor

Follow up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59230320/what-is-the-assumption-made-in-learn-you-a-haskell-when-deducing-the-kind) about *Learn You a Haskell for Great Good*.

The author, at the end of [Chapter 8](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#kinds-and-some-type-foo) declares this datatype (slightly simplified, I hope it's fine)

```
data Barry t k p = BarryV p (t k) deriving (Show)
```

and then makes it an instance of `Functor`

```
instance Functor (Barry a b) where
  fmap f (BarryV x y) = BarryV (f x) y
```

then concluding

> There we go! We just mapped the `f` over the ***first*** field.

Yes. The first. So my question is: what if I want to map over, say, the second field?

Actually the second field cannot be of a type as simple as `Int`, `Char`, `Float`, and so on; it has to be of *a type which can be obtained as a type constructor applied to a concrete type* (the italicised text is the same as <s>"parametric type", right?</s> no, it is *parametrized type*), such as `Just 3`, `Right "hello"`, `"hello"`, `[1..10]`, and so on; therefore mapping on the *second field* and mapping on the *content of the second field* seems different.

I'm really confused, but I guess the last paragraph is enough of an effort that I show.

Comment: I'd say the italicized text is "parametrized type". I'd say "parametric" has a different, technical meaning and isn't used often.

Comment: When you say "second field", do you mean the second type parameter to the `Barry` type constructor (the `k` in `data Barry t k p = ...`), or the second value parameter to the `Barry` value constructor (the `t k` in `... = Barry p (t k)`)? (I suspect part of the confusion in this question comes from not carefully distinguishing in your own mind between the two, though I am not sure.)

Comment: @DanielWagner, I've made the value ctor name different from the type ctor name, so yes, I kinda know the difference between the two, but maybe my confusion still has something to do with it (as in, I've understood the difference, but not made it fully mine).

Comment: @HTNW I tried googling, but couldn't find anything specific. what is the technical meaning of "parametric type" a.o.t. "parameterized", do you have some links or pointers? thanks.

Comment: A type or value is "parametric" in one of its type parameters if its definition does not change as that parameter changes. The opposite of "parametric in" is "indexed by." `id :: a -> a; id x = x`, `data C a = C Int`, `data D a = D a`, `Show a` are all parametric in `a`. `show :: Show a => a -> String` and `data IsInt a = a ~ Int => IsInt` are indexed by `a`. `data (:~:) a b where Refl :: a :~: a` is parametric in one argument and indexed by the other, conventionally resp. left and right. Things parametric in some of their type arguments are important because they obey "free theorems."

Comment: @HTNW thanks, so is it that all of the examples in your comment are "parameterized", but only some specific ones that you specify are also "parametric in" whatever type parameter they have?

Comment: @WillNess , should a new question spin off this comments, please link it here, as I'd be interested in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Functor` type class is too general to apply a map over the type `t k` of the second field, but it *could* apply a map over the concrete type `k` **within** the type of the second field.  So, using the terminology from your question, we can't use `Functor` to map over the second field of type `t k`, but we can use it to map over the content of type `k` within the second field of type `t k` (provided `t` is the sort of structure that allows mapping over its contents).

With respect to trying to use `Functor` to map over the type `t k`, the problem is that it allows transformations that would violate the definition of the `Barry` type.  The following function:

```
censor :: (Functor f) => f a -> f ()
censor = (() <$)
```

should apply to any functor instance, replacing fields of the targetted type `a` with unit `()`.  For example:

```
> censor (Just 5)
Just ()
> censor [1..5]
[(),(),(),(),()]
```

If `Barry` was somehow a functor in the type `t k` of its second field, then I would be able to take a valid `Barry` value:

```
> let myBarry = BarryV 10 "hello" :: Barry [] Char Int
```

and apply `censor` to it to censor its second field:

```
> censor myBarry
BarryV 10 ()
```

But what is the type of this value?  It's clearly `Barry t k Int` for some `t` and `k` such that `t k = ()`, but that's impossible.  There's no way to "split" the type `()` into two parts `t` and `k`.  So, `BarryV 10 ()` isn't a value of a valid `Barry` type, and it's existence would mean we'd constructed an invalid `Barry` type in our program.

On the other hand, we *could* create a `Functor` instance for `Barry` in the `k` parameter.  We can't do this directly, because Haskell syntax only allows us to define `Functor` instances for a type expression that target its "last" parameter.  So `Barry t k p` can be made a `Functor` in the last parameter `p` by defining a `Functor` instance for `Barry t k`, but it can't be made a `Functor` in the middle parameter `k`.

If we had a variant with the parameters in a different order:

```
data Larry p t k = LarryV p (t k) deriving (Show)
```

then we could define the `Functor` instance:

```
instance Functor (Larry p t) where
  fmap f (LarryV p tk) = LarryV p (fmap f tk)
```

This gives a type error, saying that there's no `Functor` instance for `t`, but if we restrict ourselves to defining this instance only when we have `Functor t`, it works fine:

```
instance Functor t => Functor (Larry p t) where
  fmap f (LarryV p tk) = LarryV p (fmap f tk)
```

Now, as long as `t` is a `Functor`, we have `Larry p t` a `Functor`.  For example:

```
> let myLarry = LarryV 10 "hello"
> :t myLarry
myLarry :: Num p => Larry p [] Char
> import Data.Char
> fmap toUpper myLarry
LarryV 10 "HELLO"
```

This works because `t = []` is a `Functor`, so we get the instance we need.

Note that in practical code, instead of introducing a new type `Larry`, the standard way of defining a `Functor` instance in a "middle" parameter is to use a `newtype` wrapper, something like:

```
newtype Barry' p t k = Barry' (Barry t k p)
instance Functor t => Functor (Barry' p t) where
  fmap f (Barry' (BarryV p tk)) = Barry' (BarryV p (fmap f tk))
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to just make a function with your type as a concrete type that does it:

```
mymap :: (t1 k1 -> t2 k2) -> Barry t1 k1 p -> Barry t2 k2 p
mymap f (BarryV x y) = BarryV x (f y)
```

If you really wanted to do it with an existing typeclass, you could probably chain together enough transformations through wrapper types like `Product` or `Compose` to get something like a `Bifunctor` to pop out, but I don't think that's worth doing in this case.

Comment: So this answers seems to boil down to _you can't do it easily if you want to use an existing typeclass as `Functor`_. In principle this is an answer to my question, but it'd be nice if you could help me understand why it is not possible. It would help me understand the type system.